# How to I preload existing files and display them in the blueimp upload table?

Tags: upload, blueimp

I am using the jquery-ui version of Blueimp upload and I like how I can format a table and display files that were just uploaded. But I'd like to use it as a file manager as well so I want to preload existing files and display than as if they were just uploaded. How can I do that? A sample link to where someone else has addressed this would suffice.  BTW, I am uploading several different file types, not just images.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also had the same problem. It is not magic how it works. I recommend to examine the UploadHandler.php file. Then you will be able to modify this plugin accordind to your needs.

The code above in your second post is just an ajax call to the uploader script (by default index.php in server/php/ folder). The call method is set to "get" by default in $.ajax object.

Open the UploadHandler.php file and go to the class method "initialize(...)". You will see how the call with "get" handled. UploadHandler calls the class method this->get(.:.) to prepare and send the list of existing files. If you use other upload directory, you need pass a parameter to the UploadHänder. Simply chage the url property in the $.ajax object like :

```
url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url')+'?otherDir='+myDir,
```

then you should initialize the option property of the UploadHandler before you create a new UploadHandler object like this:

```
$otherDir = trim($_REQUEST['otherDir']);
$otherDir_url = [anyURL] .'/'.$otherDir;//so that the files can be downloaded by clicking on the link

$options = array(
'upload_dir'=> $otherDir,
'upload_url'=> $otherDir_url,
);

$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($options);
```

Comment: @Selim I'm having trouble with this implementation and since your answer is dated, I'd like to ask you to review your answer and inform me / us if this is still relevant with the latest version? Additionally, Could i interest you in sharing any clues here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090215/how-to-download-manage-images-using-blueimp-jquery-file-upload

Answer (score 32):

Or without an ajax call:

1. Prepare array containing details of existing files, e.g:

   ```
   var files = [
       {
           "name":"fileName.jpg",
           "size":775702,
           "type":"image/jpeg",
           "url":"http://mydomain.com/files/fileName.jpg",
           "deleteUrl":"http://mydomain.com/files/fileName.jpg",
           "deleteType":"DELETE"
       },
       {
           "name":"file2.jpg",
           "size":68222,
           "type":"image/jpeg",
           "url":"http://mydomain.com/files/file2.jpg",
           "deleteUrl":"http://mydomain.com/files/file2.jpg",
           "deleteType":"DELETE"
       }
   ];
   ```
2. Call done callback

   ```
   var $form = $('#fileupload');        

   // Init fileuploader if not initialized
   // $form.fileupload();

   $form.fileupload('option', 'done').call($form, $.Event('done'), {result: {files: files}});
   ```

Comment: Another attribute that can be added to the files array is `thumbnailUrl` which contains the path to the thumbnail preview of the stored image to be displayed

Comment: Not sure about this, wouldn't you want those files to preload when the page loads instead of on a file upload?  That makes more sense to me.

Comment: Disregard what I previously said!  This works like a charm.  The only thing I don't fully understand is the deleteURL... Can anyone explain that?

Comment: For future references, please note that your files[] may look differently. Alert the object from the done: function in the fileupload-ui.js to be sure how it should be structured.

Comment: Very intuitive way to set the files array.  Seems that the author has decided to make a laugh upon the users. A simple `$(form).fileupload({ files: files });` would definitely make more sense. Anyway thanks for the working hack, was very hard to dig a working answer to a trivial question.

Comment: Hey, guys! Can anyone explain – where does this code should be implemented? (main.js, UploadHandler.php, simple page?, etc). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! This was the answer for me.

Comment: MagyaDev or @Cristian E, Might I interest either of you in a chat to help demystify your answers? I'd like to do this using PHP and JS and am very novice at building code from scratch

Comment: MagyaDev, Could you please better explain your code? Im fumbling with it and would greatly appreciate a few mins of your time

Answer (score 5):

Found the code in the main js file... It wasn't obvious how it worked. Got it working just fine.

```
// Load existing files:
$.ajax({
    url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
    dataType: 'json',
    context: $('#fileupload')[0]
}).done(function (result) {
    $(this).fileupload('option', 'done').call(this, null, {result: result});
});
```

Comment: Can you explain how you did it? And can it be done through a url variable? Like php?foldername=customfolder

Comment: I completely forgot. :) I use the code differently now so this isn't a current problem. I believe the call above does it, where the url for the ajax url is actually a jquery selector that falls fileupload.

Answer (score 1):

If any of you looking at this is doing it in .NET, find this: (for me it is in application.js

For a fairly recent version, there is a function

```
    // Load existing files:
$.getJSON($('#fileupload form').prop('action'), function(files) {

files = somethingelse;

    var fu = $('#fileupload').data('fileupload');
    fu._adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(-files.length);
    fu._renderDownload(files)
        .appendTo($('#fileupload .files'))

        .fadeIn(function() {
            // Fix for IE7 and lower:
            $(this).show();
        });
});
```

Inside the application.js
I'm doing it for .NET though, and actually needed this gone.

Then set your somethingelse to either your files or "" depending on what you want to show. If you remove the line files = somethingelse then it will preload all files from the folder.